# Issues with saving Linux and Windows folders on the same USB?

Tags: linux-mint, windows, usb, shared-folders

I'm wondering if folders work differently when set up by Linux than they do when set up by Windows.

Here's what I want to do:

1. Go into Linux Mint, plug in a brand new USB stick, and create a folder on it called "backup" with four folders under it for my four different computers
2. Go into Windows 7, access sub folder "A" on the USB stick (under "backup"), and drag "my documents" including sub-folders into folder "A"
3. Go into Lunux Mint and add / modify / delete folders under "my documents" under folder "A" on the USB stick -- folders which were originally set up in Windows

Would I have any issues doing this?

(The reason I got suspicious is that I noticed Windows uses front-slashes between folders, and Linux uses back-slashes, so I didn't know if there was some difference in how they're structured? I had an expensive USB stick that suddenly stopped working altogether after I did something similar to what I typed out above. Coincidence?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not have any issues, assuming that you format the USB as FAT32 or NTFS (native to Windows, but which Linux Mint can handle) and not ext4 or btrfs (native to Linux, but that Windows cannot handle out of the box).

The backward slashes/forward slashes are a display artefact when printing a full path, they are not actually on the disc (just the directory names are there that get concatenated using the slash when displaying).

The only thing you should watch is that Windows has more restrictions than Linux on filenames, so don't try to create anything named to exotic using Linux. The filesystem might restrict you, but I would stay with `A-Z0-9_` for filenames/directories.